# WCF - ClientMessageInspector error reporting

Tags: c#, wcf, validation, soapfault

I'm writing a web service at the moment, with a custom behaviour for validating input messages against an XML schema. However, I don't understand how I can report any of those errors back to the client as SOAP faults.

I've extended the IClientMessageInspector and IDispatchMessageInspector to intercept and validate the messages, and am catching validation errors in a validation event handler. The problem comes here: when I throw a new FaultException at this point, it goes unhandled and crashes; using both a code client and the WCF Test Client.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [IErrorHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx) to customize the response which is returned when an exception occurs.

Comment: Would that allow me to pass a SOAP fault back to the client before the data hits the action it's intended for?